# Does the Torah require a Jewish Monarchy

Tags: rambam, malchut-royalty

Does the Torah require a Jewish Monarchy?

When the people asked Nevi Samuel to appoint a King he strenuously objected to the appointment of a King! (1 Samuel [8:6](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.8.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [11-18](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.8.11-18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Maimonides ([Hilchos Melachim 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.1?lang=bi)) states that it is an OBLIGATION to appoint a King when we enter the Land of Israel, based on the passage in [Devarim 17:14-20](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.14-20?lang=bi&aliyot=0). What do other authorities state, in light of Samuel's displeasure?

It seems to me that this passage in Devarim 17 must be read in light of the passage ([Shemos 19.6](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) in which Israel is called "a kingdom of Priests and a holy nation!"

Additionally, why does the Torah say in [Devarim 17:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), "one whom HaShem shall choose?"

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You quote Maimonides that it is an obligation. Are you asking if Maimonides was mistaken? If some other authority disagrees? Something else?

Comment: How about what Maimonides states, in light of Samuel's displeasure? "Since it is a mitzvah to appoint a king, why was God displeased with the people's request of a king from Samuel? Because they made their request in a spirit of complaint. Rather than seeking to fulfill the mitzvah of appointing a king, they were simply intent on rejecting the Prophet Samuel as implied by God's reply to him (I Samuel 8:7): 'It is not you, but Me they have rejected'" ([Hilkhot Melakhim u-MilChamot 1:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188345/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-1.htm)).

Comment: Related issues have been discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34690/could-a-religious-man-be-an-anarchist/34734#34734)

Answer (score 1):

[Deuteronomy 17:14-15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.14-15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

(14) "When you come to the land the L-rd, your G-d, is giving you, and you possess it and live therein, and you say, "I will set a king over myself, like all the nations around me,"

(15) "You shall set a king over you, one whom the L-rd, your G-d, chooses; **from among your brothers**, you shall set a king over yourself; **you shall not appoint a foreigner over yourself**, one who is not your brother."

As you see the Torah requires a Jewish monarchy.

Comment: Actually if anything this should be a proof that monarchy is not required because it says when you say your want a king. The question really is now that we've already asked for a king but have kind of lost it over the years do we have to reinstall a king again or do we decide once more if we want a king.

Comment: Netziv explains that the mitzva is to install a monarchy **when you are ready to have one.**

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Yeshayahu Hollander, a member of the Sanhedrin said,

“The Jews are commanded to be a nation of priests,” Rabbi Hollander [told Breaking Israel News,] citing a verse in Exodus.

```
But you shall be to Me a kingdom of priests and a holy nation.’ These are the words that you shall speak to the children of Yisrael.” Exodus 19:6
```

Clearly, the Torah is stating that Yisrael is to be "a kingdom of priests and a holy nation."

Electing a king is qualified by the statement in the passuk,  "one whom the L-rd, your G-d, chooses;" which is further qualified by the passage in 2 Samuel 6.21 [And David said unto Michal: 'Before the L-RD, who ***chose*** me above thy father, and above all his house, to appoint me prince over the people of the L-RD, over Israel, before the L-RD will I make merry.] and also qualified by ["Howbeit the L-RD, the G-D of Israel, ***chose*** me out of all the house of my father to be king over Israel for ever; for He hath chosen Judah to be prince, and in the house of Judah, the house of my father, and among the sons of my father He took ***pleasure in me*** to make me king over all Israel;"] OBVIOUSLY, HaShem chose David to be King over all Yisrael, the prophesied "kingdom of priests and a holy nation!"